# How to auto center my position after function getCurrentPosition with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I created a function that displays a marker on the map once geolocated, and the display does not center automatically.
What's the parameters for auto center my marker ?
I think this proble in on the getCenter.

```
import { useState} from 'react';
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";

import icon from "./iconPosition";

export default function LocationMarker() {
    const map = useMap();
    let [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState([0, 0]);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          setCurrentPosition([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
        });

            let latlng = currentPosition;
            L.marker(latlng, { icon })
              .addTo(map)
              .bindPopup("Vous êtes ici")
              .openPopup();
              map.getCenter();
              map.getZoom();
    }
  
    return (null)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the center and not to get the current center.

Replace

```
map.getCenter();
map.getZoom();
```

with

```
map.panTo(latlng)
```